# Error compiling storyboard files using Xcode 6 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, ios8, xcode6

My app was building fine in Xcode 6 Beta 4. I updated to Beta 5 today and ran into 2 errors:

The file “Storyboard_iPad-SBPartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

What is that SBPartialInfo.plist? I could not search for it via spotlight. My Storyboard files are storyboard_iphone and storyboard_ipad

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing the following error after upgrading to Beta5:

`Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255`

As is often the case, quitting and reopening Xcode seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: This only answers part of the question. Can you give some more details about what the SBPartialInfo.plist file is?

Answer (score 1):

try to uncheck "Use Auto Layout" if it checked

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help -- but I had the same latter error (the one with the error code 255). What I did was run the simulator with iOS7 (that worked fine for me). Then when I was there, I reset the simulator, cleaned, and ran with iOS8. So you could try resetting the simulator, cleaning, and then building. After doing the above, my project ran fine on iOS8.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. It didn't work. Reset iOS7, iOS8 simulators. Deleted project derived data. Close and restart Xcode. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is having a problem compiling your storyboard, but the error is not particularly helpful.

I have seen this happen in a few occasions, but most often due to a Popover Segue with a missing or illegal anchor such as a UITableViewCell or an item in a cell's contentView.

So, check any recently added Segues.